# Xcode 9.3 set coverage data settings

Tags: ios, iphone, swift4, xcode9

Any of you knows where the "coverage data" setting is in Xcode 9.3?, according to apple should be here:

[image]

But in any of my Xcode project doesn't show it all. For example:

[image]

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's been moved under the Options tab:

[image: Code Coverage]